# Exporting maps to pdf

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I need to create a PDF book of all counties in a counties shapefile.

I now have to use a cursor and a for loop to get individual counties, but I'm not sure how to go from there.

I'm not allowed to use  data driven pages and also I need to scale up the maps a little bit.

Here's part i need help with:

`with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,"COUNTY") as cursor:
      for county in cursor:
        df1.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc ,pdfPath) with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,"COUNTY") as cursor:
      for county in cursor:
        df1.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc ,pdfPath)`

This code export the whole map at once.

Comment: Does this have to be done using ArcPy?  I think data driven pages could do what you are wanting done.

Comment: @ed.hankins It's noted in the OP that they cannot use DDP, although I don't know why.

Comment: Please make an effort to format code and include tings like personal pronouns in future.

Comment: @nwduncan doh! I think I skimmed right by that when I was reading the question.  When I read it more carefully it sounds like homework which is  way DDP isn't considered a valid solution, at least thats my guess.  And for the OP I think you will need a little more detail than what you have if you want to get any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the "zoomToSelectedFeatures" function, but rather get the extent of the selected feature's shape and set the Dataframe extent to that.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,["SHAPE@","COUNTY"]) as cursor:
   for county in cursor:
      df1.extent = county[0].extent
      arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mapdoc ,pdfPath)
```